# error con DataReader (sql server y c#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

muy buenas, estoy creando una aplicacion la cual necesita una coneccion con una base de datos sql server.

al  compilar mi codigo la conección con sql server funciona, pero cuando llega al sqldatareader sale un error (must declare the scalar variable)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Ins_Med_WPF.pages;
using System.Data;



namespace Ins_Med_WPF.pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para admin_login.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class admin_login : Page
    {
        public admin_login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string id_admin { get; set; }
        public string contraseña { get; set; }
        private void btniniciosesion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-5REI37J ;database=insmed2.0;integrated security =true");
            conexion.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("funciono");
            string cadena = "select id_admin, contraseña from ADMINISTRADOR where id_admin= + @idusuario";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@id_admin", SqlDbType.Int);
            comando.Parameters["@id_admin"].Value = int.Parse(idusuario.Text);
            SqlDataReader registros = comando.ExecuteReader();

            string cadena2 = "select  contraseña from ADMINISTRADOR where id_admin=" + contraseñal;
            SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
            SqlDataReader registro2 = comando.ExecuteReader();



            if (registros.Read() && registro2.Read())
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new admin_panel());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

este es el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quien me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria muchisimo.

no se que mas escribir, la pagina me pide que añada mas detalles pero creo que eso es todo asi que este parrafo solo es para rellenar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta el parámetro es `@idusuario`, ese mismo se debe asignar con `Parameters.Add()`

```
string cadena = "select id_admin, contraseña from ADMINISTRADOR where id_admin =  @idusuario";
// el parámetro es @idusuario y su valor es idusuario.Text
comando.Parameters.Add("@idusuario", idusuario.Text);
```